# Laravel: sending empty session on callback request

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

i just create a custom `404.blade.php` page to show 404 error inside my layout and i made some changes in `app\Exceptions\Handler.php` file.

**My Code:**

```
if ($exception instanceof TokenMismatchException){

     return redirect($request->fullUrl())->with('csrf_error',"Oops! Seems you couldn't submit form for a long time. Please try again.");
}
if($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException){
     if(Auth::guard('org')->check() == false){
         return response()->view('errors.web-404', [], 404);
     }
}else{
     if($exception instanceof \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException || $exception instanceof MethodNotAllowedHttpException){
          return parent::render($request, $exception);
     }else{
          if(Auth::guard('org')->check()){
                return response()->view('errors.error-page',['exception'=>$exception,'request'=>$request],500);
          }else{
                return response()->view('errors.web-error-page',['exception'=>$exception,'request'=>$request],500);
          }                
     }
}

return parent::render($request, $exception);
```

It was showing `Auth::guard('org')->check()` always `false` because of session not start. So i did some changes in my `Kernel.php` file and all was working fine.

**Kernel.php**

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings::class,
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull::class,

    // Added to show 404 error inside layout

    \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
    \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
];
```

But now I just noticed that all session flash messages and validation error messages are not working. I think it is because on `return back()` session again initialize in `Kernel.php`

Can any one tell me how i can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this lines in kernel.php file's middleware array

```
protected $middleware = [
    // ...
    \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
    \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class
];
```

Good luck...

Comment: its working for my custom 404 error, but still same problem. Session become empty on `return back()` :(

Comment: where you are trying to access session?

Comment: where ever i used `Session::flash('success,'Successfully done!'')` then flash messages and validation error messages become empty.

Comment: might be chance like you using wrong technique or kind of bug is there